# Diferença entre dois arrays com TypeScript ou ES6

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

Como posso obter a diferença entre dois `Arrays` de objetos usando `TypeScript` ou `ES6`?

Tentei fazer usando [SET](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```
   let arr1 = new Set(lista1);
   let arr2 = new Set(lista2);
   let difference = new Set(
       [arr1 ].filter(x => !arr2.has(x)));
```

Porém não deu certo, esse é o resultado que recebo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma os valores não são listados, talvez não seja a maneira mais apropriada pra fazer o que quero.

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do que os arrays têm dentro e de como queres o resultado da comparação? Porque há maneiras diferentes de fazer... queres as diferênças em uma delas? em ambas? estás a comparar strings ou objetos? etc... Precisas de usar o Set ou são arrays "normais"? Já experimentaste `let diff = arr1.filter(x => arr2.indexOf(x) == -1);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma:

```
let mapChamada = chamada.map(item => item.Matricula);
let mapPessoa = pessoas.map(item => item.Matricula);

let diff = mapChamada.map((Matricula, index) => {
  if (mapPessoa.indexOf(Matricula) < 0) {
    return chamada[index];
  }
}).concat(mapPessoa.map((Matricula, index) => {
  if (mapChamada.indexOf(Matricula) < 0) {
    return pessoas[index];
  }
})).filter(item => item != undefined);

console.log(diff);
```

Meus dois `arrays` são estes:

```
let chamada= [{
      Matricula: 434,
      Nome: 'Diego Augusto',
      PessoaId: 'bc61b0a1-2b8e-4c93-a175-21949ff2b240'
}];

let pessoas = [{
     Matricula: 434,
     Nome: 'Diego Augusto',
     PessoaId: 'bc61b0a1-2b8e-4c93-a175-21949ff2b240'
  }, {
     Matricula: 431,
     Nome: 'Crislayne',
     PessoaId: '11576497-7632-4c1b-9806-fed24b7608c2'
  }];
```

O Resultado da diferença foi:

```
diff [{
     Matricula: 431,
     Nome: 'Crislayne',
     PessoaId: '11576497-7632-4c1b-9806-fed24b7608c2'
  }];
```